# Calling OpenBUGS in R not working

Tags: r, winbugs

I have been trying to run a R code to use OpenBugs. It was working well till yesterday and I do not know what I did that it started showing some error. Then I decided to see if some simple example works well. So I tried the schools example present in [`R2WinBUGS` vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2WinBUGS/vignettes/R2WinBUGS.pdf).

The model in file schools.txt is

```
sink("schools.txt")
cat("
      model {
      for (j in 1:J)
      {
        y[j] ~ dnorm (theta[j], tau.y[j])
        theta[j] ~ dnorm (mu.theta, tau.theta)
        tau.y[j] <- pow(sigma.y[j], -2)
      }
      mu.theta ~ dnorm (0.0, 1.0E-6)
      tau.theta <- pow(sigma.theta, -2)
      sigma.theta ~ dunif (0, 1000)
    }",fill=TRUE)
sink()
```

The code for running the rest of the program is as follows:

```
    data(schools)
 J <- nrow(schools)
 y <- schools$estimate
 sigma.y <- schools$sd
 data <- list ("J", "y", "sigma.y")

inits <- function()
{ 
  list(theta = rnorm(J, 0, 100), mu.theta = rnorm(1, 0, 100),sigma.theta = runif(1, 0, 100))
}

schools.sim <- bugs(data, inits, model.file = "schools.txt",parameters = c("theta", "mu.theta", "sigma.theta"),n.chains = 3, n.iter = 1000)
```

**Unfortunately, I am getting the same error as before.**

```
 > schools.sim <- bugs(data, inits, model.file = "schools.txt",parameters = c("theta", "mu.theta", "sigma.theta"),n.chains = 3, n.iter = 1000)
    Error in sd(as.vector(ai)) : unused argument(s) (as.vector(ai))
```

I have also tried specifying `program=c('OpenBugs')` **But that gives me another weird error given that OpenBugs is in the path**

```
     Error in bugs(data, inits, model.file = "schools.txt", parameters = c("theta",  : 
  unused argument(s) (program = c("OpenBugs"))
```

**EDIT**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] abind_1.4-0        rjags_3-9          R2WinBUGS_2.1-18   BRugs_0.8-0        R2OpenBUGS_3.2-2.1
[6] LearnBayes_2.12    coda_0.16-1        lattice_0.20-10   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] boot_1.3-7    grid_2.15.2   plyr_1.8      stringr_0.6.2 tools_2.15.2
```

`traceback()` gives...

```
> traceback()
No traceback available
```

**EDIT-2**

```
  > getAnywhere("sd")
2 differing objects matching ‘sd’ were found
in the following places
  .GlobalEnv
  package:stats
  namespace:stats
Use [] to view one of them`
```

How should I remove the `sd` that I defined and that is sitting in `.GlobalEnv`?

**EDIT-3**

**Problem solved. I removed the object `sd` from the workspace and everything worked.**

Comment: Have you tried closing the current R session and opening up a clean new session? Make sure you aren't just reloading your old session.

Comment: Yes, I tried but the same result!

Comment: results of `sessionInfo()`?  `traceback()`?

Comment: I think you've somehow gotten a weird version of `sd` defined. What are the results of `getAnywhere("sd")$where`?  It *should* be `"package:stats"   "namespace:stats"`.  If you did `attach(schools)` I can see that would create another object named `sd` in your workspace, but that shouldn't cause problems because it's not a function ...

Comment: Thanks for `getAnywhere`. Please see EDIT-2

Comment: `rm("sd")` (or `rm(sd)`) should do it.

Comment: Thanks. I know rm but I was wondering if there is any command/function which removed an object from an environment

Comment: ??? `rm` does have an `envir` argument ...

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you very much for helping me to remove the error I was struggling with.

Comment: @BenBolker can you post this as an answer so Stat-R can accept it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've somehow gotten a weird version of `sd` defined. What are the results of `getAnywhere("sd")$where`? It should be `"package:stats" "namespace:stats"`. If you did `attach(schools)` I can see that would create another object named `sd` in your workspace, but that shouldn't cause problems because it's not a function.

Solution: `rm(sd)` or `rm("sd")` (the latter is probably better)

Comment: I defined another function named `sd` in my `Rprofile.site` file and that is why I was getting the error message. `R` was using the sd defined in `.Global`. Thanks